# Evaluation of mail server configuration

Tags: spam, blacklist, spam-filter, greylisting, rbl

I have a mail server configured to use DNS real-time blacklists (DNSRBLs), e.g. zen.spamhaus.org, to determine whether delivered email is spam or not.

I would like to evaluate my mail server's configuration since I am still receiving A LOT of spam.

How can I do that? Is it possible to somehow send an email from a blacklisted server for test purposes? Are such blacklisted test servers available at hand?

Comment: You should have a look through your maillog, if mail is rejected due to a response from the blacklist server, this information will be available in the log.

Comment: Thanks, you can add that as an answer and I will accept it. I see that blacklisting works, however my email is so heavily spammed that around 30 spam messages per day make it through blacklisting + greylisting + spamassasin.

Comment: Have a look at spamassassin then, especially at the rules that the messages that the missed spam hit on, and see if adjusting them upwards has a positive effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any information about email rejected due to a response from a blacklist server will be included in the log file corresponding to your email server. This is primarily to assist the mail server administrator when they need to determine the cause(s) for non-delivery.